# Ajax: Multiple select with PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am using 3 selects to get items from database. Once we choose the first option, the second select appears and once we choose the second - the third select appears.

How can I do it with `jQuery` / `Ajax` / `PHP`?

The code:

```
<select name="1">
    <option value="1">op1</option>
    <option value="2">op2</option>
    <option value="3">op3</option>
</select>
```

So, for example, once  we choose `op1`, this will run a query to search in the database and return results in `select2`:

```
<select name="2">
     <option value="11">op11</option>
     <option value="12">op12</option>
     <option value="13">op13</option>
</select>
```

And then once we choose op11, a query is run and search in the database  to return results in `select3`:

```
<select name="3">
     <option value="111">op111</option>
     <option value="112">op112</option>
     <option value="113">op113</option>
</select>
```

How can I achieve this, please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Easiest thing is to use a plugin: https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+chained+selects

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is not really concrete but i will try. Server side you need to do an request to your MYSQL db and return the data in an array like: echo json_encode($data);

```
function getSelectData(number,value){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        data: {value:value},    
        url: 'file.php?field='+number+'',
        success: function (data) {  
            returndata = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

            var nextnumber = parseInt(number) + 1;  
            $('select[name='+newvalue+']').html('');

            // each the result here and append it to te next select
            $.each(data, function( index, item ) {
              $('select[name='+nextnumber+']').append('<option value="'+item.value+'">'+item.name+'</option>');
            });


        }
    });     


}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('select').change(function(){
        getSelectData($(this).attr('name'),$(this).find('option:selected').val());
    });

});
```

Comment: what is the intention behind 'async:false'?

Comment: You are right. I,ve removed it. Async request is oké here.

Comment: will this do the job for 3 seperated selects? I am looking for something like http://demos.thesoftwareguy.in/multiple-dropdown-jquery-ajax-php/

Comment: I,ve changed my answer. This is only the client side part. Server side you need to get something of the db and send it in an PHP array like array(0 => array ('value' = $value, 'name' => $name))

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="1" id="select1" onchange="get_option_from_ajax('file1.php?post_value='+this.value, '#select2')">
   <option value="1">op1</option>
   <option value="2">op2</option>
   <option value="3">op3</option>
</select>

<select name="2" id="select2" onchange="get_option_from_ajax('file2.php?post_value='+this.value, '#select3')">
<option value="11">op11</option>
<option value="12">op12</option>
<option value="13">op13</option>
</select>

<select name="3" id="select3">
<option value="111">op111</option>
<option value="112">op112</option>
<option value="113">op113</option>
</select>
```

**JS AJAX FUNCTION**

```
<script>
get_option_from_ajax(file, container_id)
{
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      document.getElementById(container_id).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET",file,true);
  xmlhttp.send(); 
}
</script>
```

**JQUERY AJAX FUNCTION**

```
<script>
get_option_from_ajax(file, container_id)
{
  var res = file.split("?");
  var url = res[0];
  var params = res[1];

  $.ajax({
   url: url,
   data: params, 
   success: function(result) {
     $("#"+container_id).html(result);
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

**Description :**

**1.** first call ajax function on change event on the select options
   function has two parameters

```
  A. file with selected value, 
  B. container id where the response content has to be put
```

**2.** corresponding php filename has to be passed in to the ajax function

**3.** output of php files are options. only

Comment: why dont you use jquery?

Comment: why not Can be used jquery also. as per choice

Comment: question is tagged with jquery only. :)

Comment: @AnoopJoshi and JelleP now i have also added a jquery function

Comment: I am looking for something like this http://demos.thesoftwareguy.in/multiple-dropdown-jquery-ajax-php/